# A casual way to say approximately?

Tags: phrases, idiomatic-language

I'm looking for a casual way to say approximately in this dialog. Would *there around* be idiomatic?

> *How many close friends do you have?*
>
> *I don't know... Seven.*
>
> *Seven?*
>
> *Yeah. **There around.***

Comment: How about 'thereabouts' or 'more or less'?

Comment: There's also "give or take".... or my personal favourite: "ish"  -  As in "I'll be there at 7ish"

Comment: It sounds *about* right.

Comment: I'd also use "roughly"..."I don't know, roughly seven" or "Yeah, roughly" (a bit more colloquial in UK English and short for "roughly speaking").

https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/roughly-speaking

Comment: "There around" is correct, but is only natural in certain varieties of English. The other answers above are natural in any standard variety of English.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest:

> Yeah, about that.

perhaps spoken as 'bout tha'

Other suggestions from comments:

'thereabouts' or 'more or less' "give or take". "It sounds about right" or "roughly" as in "roughly seven"